# Declaring an anonymous type member with a simple name

Tags: c#, anonymous-types

When you try to compile this:

```
var car = new { "toyota", 5000 };
```

You will get the compiler error *"Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access."* because the compiler is not able to infer the name of the properties from the respective expressions. **That makes total sense.**

What makes me curious is that the error message implies three valid ways to declare a type member. Member assignment and member access are obvious:

```
// member assignment
var v = new { Amount = 108, Message = "Hello" };

// member access
var productQuery = 
    from prod in products
    select new { prod.Color, prod.Price };
```

What would be an example of declaring with a *simple name*?

Googling and the related questions on SO result in examples of *member assignment* and *member access* only.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As far as I know, `simple name` declaration is this:

```
var amount = 10;
var whatever = "hello";

var newType = { amount, whatever }
```

Which will automatically create an anonymous type equal to:

```
var newType = { amount = amount, whatever = whatever }
```

Comment: In fact, simple name is a specific term from the [C# spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691350(v=vs.71).aspx). Quote: `A simple-name consists of an identifier, optionally followed by a type argument list:
simple-name:
identifier   type-argument-listopt
` page 158, paragraph **7.6.2** from C# 5.0 spec. MSDN and language specification is a out of sync a bit. [Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) gives a deeper definition