# Joining to Lists via LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list of objects

**Tasks**

```
    public string ProjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ProjectManager { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
```

**Projects**

```
    public string Number { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Manager { get; set; }
    public string Customer { get; set; }
```

**Example data**

Tasks

```
Projectnumber | Name          | ProjectManager | Customer 
    7780      | Buy container | NULL           | NULL
    7781      | Block budget  | NULL           | NULL
```

Projects

```
Nubmer        | Title         | Manager        | Customer 
    7780      | Surface       | Bill Gates     | Microsoft 
    7781      | iWatch        | Tim Cook       | Apple
```

I want to get a `List<Task>` as result:

```
Projectnumber | Name          | ProjectManager | Customer 
    7780      | Buy container | Bill Gates     | Microsoft 
    7781      | Block budget  | Tim Cook       | Apple
```

What i tried so far:

```
List<Task> spTasks = SPRepo.GetAllTasksByResourceTeam();
List<Project> projects = PWARepo.GetAllProjects();

    List<Task> joinedSPTasks = from a in spTasks
                        join b in projects on a.ProjectNumber equals b.Number
                        select new Task() {
                        a.Projectnumber = a.Projectnumber,
                        a.Name = a.Name,
                        a.ProjectManager = b.ProjectManager,
                        a.Customer = b.Manager
                        };
```

Why I can't assign values to properties? I get the following error in Visual Studio:

```
Error: Invalid anonymous type member decorator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment simple name or member access.
```

***Note: These List of objects are coming from different sources. it is not possible to join them in the source system (for example a database via table joins)!***

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Declaring an anonymous type member with a simple name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26590968/declaring-an-anonymous-type-member-with-a-simple-name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are selecting the values in dynamic object. instead of using select new{, use select new Task{

```
        List<Task> joinedSPTasks = (from a in spTasks
                join b in projects on a.ProjectNumber equals b.Number
                select new Task{
                    Projectnumber = a.Projectnumber,
                    Name = a.Name,
                    ProjectManager = b.ProjectManager,
                    Customer = b.Manager
                    }).ToList();
```

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Data.Task>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: You might want to put a .ToList() in the end.

      (from a in spTasks
                join b in projects on a.ProjectNumber equals b.Number
                select new Task{
                    a.Projectnumber = a.Projectnumber,
                    a.Name = a.Name,
                    a.ProjectManager = b.ProjectManager,
                    a.Customer = b.Manager
                    }).ToList()

Comment: When i remove a. from the properties like Projectnumber = a.Projectnumer ... it works now. Please update answer and i will mark it as accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
List<Task> joinedSPTasks = from a in spTasks
                    join b in projects on a.ProjectNumber equals b.Number
                    select new Task(){
                        ProjectNumber = a.Projectnumber,
                        Name = a.Name,
                        ProjectManager = b.ProjectManager,
                        Customer = b.Manager
                        };
```

or

```
var joinedSPTasks = from a in spTasks
                    join b in projects on a.ProjectNumber equals b.Number
                    select new {
                        ProjectNumber = a.Projectnumber,
                        Name = a.Name,
                        ProjectManager = b.ProjectManager,
                        Customer = b.Manager
                        };
```

REmove "a." from start of anonymous member names. Second option is for using anonymous type. You need to use `var` keyword to declare anonymous type

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Data.Task>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Answer (score 2):

It's unclear if you want to update the current tasks or create new one.

creating new one will be like this

```
var joinedSPTasks = from a in spTasks
                    join b in projects on a.ProjectNumber equals b.Number
                    select new Task(){
                        Projectnumber = a.Projectnumber,
                        Name = a.Name,
                        ProjectManager = b.ProjectManager,
                        Customer = b.Manager
                        };
```

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Data.Task>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

Comment: fixed. change the return type to `var`.

Comment: changed it to `IEnumerable<Data.Task>` - someone who doesn't understand how to get `List<T>`from `IEnumerable<T>` you shouldn't fix the error with changing it to `var`

Comment: `var` is very clean&common when the return type is clear from the context.

Comment: matter of taste! But explaining someone how to fix this exception with changing the returntype to var, is definitely wrong.

Comment: I get your point. I could have add explanation about LINQ return type.

Answer (score 0):

The anonymous type you are creating is wrong - it should be like this:

```
                joinedSPTasks = from a in spTasks
                join b in projects on a.ProjectNumber equals b.Number
                select new {
                    Projectnumber = a.Projectnumber,
                    Name = a.Name,
                    ProjectManager = b.ProjectManager,
                    Customer = b.Manager
                    };
```

you can actually drop the Parameter naming and just write it like this:

```
select new { a.Projectnumber, a.Name, b.ProjectManager, b.Manager };
```

Comment: Error CS0266 Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Data.Task>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Data.Task>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)